# VML not working in HTML email

Tags: firefox, html-email

Below is the code generated by https://buttons.cm/ for feedback button:

```html
<div><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="#" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:200px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1e3650" fill="t">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/0xPEf.gif" color="#556270" />
    <w:anchorlock/>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Click for Feedback!</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="#"
style="background-color:#556270;background-image:url(https://i.imgur.com/0xPEf.gif);border:1px solid #1e3650;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:200px; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Click for Feedback!</a></div>
```

Using the same code, I am getting below error:

1. Outlook + word : Height is reducing; I tried giving padding but no use.
2. In Firefox + yahoo : Anchor tag has underline with it.

Any suggestions to overcome this?

Comment: Where's the closing statements?

Comment: Which closing statement are you referring to? VML code is closed in the snippet and also the div has closing.

Comment: Add `text-decoration:none;` to your anchor tag and increase the height of VML (to say 50px) that should work.